# How to set hashed password for MySQL database user

Tags: mysql, password-hash

My boss would like me to write a script for our developers to run that would create a new DB user on their dev builds.  He does not want me to have the actual password in the code; only the hash.  I have the hashed password, but when I try creating a user with that hashed password; it just hashes the hashed password again.

`CREATE USER 'test_user1'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';`
shows me the hashed password is "*2470C0C06DEE42FD1618BB99005ADCA2EC9D1E19"

But if I attempt...
 `CREATE USER 'test_user2'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '*2470C0C06DEE42FD1618BB99005ADCA2EC9D1E19';`

"password" is not actually my password for test_user2.

I have also tried the following `UPDATE` but "password" still doesn't work for test-user2:

`` UPDATE `mysql`.`user` SET `authentication_string` = '*2470C0C06DEE42FD1618BB99005ADCA2EC9D1E19' WHERE (`Host` = 'localhost') and (`User` = 'test_user2'); ``

How can I prevent it from hashing the value I'm entering, since I already know the hashed value?

I have also run `GRANT SELECT` for both users in my testing.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The key is to use `IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password AS 'hash'`. Consider the following, for example:

```
CREATE USER 'jeffrey'@'localhost'
  IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password AS 'hash-goes-here';
```

Relevant excerpt from the documentation:

> IDENTIFIED WITH auth_plugin AS 'auth_string'
>
> Sets the account authentication plugin to auth_plugin and stores the
>   'auth_string' value as is in the mysql.user account row. If the plugin
>   requires a hashed string, the string is assumed to be already hashed
>   in the format the plugin requires.

Comment: OMG.  This was it.  And the key is to use `AS` not `BY`.  If you use `BY`, it will still hash it; if you use `AS` it will use your hashed value.
THANK-YOU!!!

Answer (score 0):

I think (might be wrong here not sure) that it actually doesn't matter how many times a hash is hashed it still represents the same password. So you can run the same hash check on your input, and the output of the MySQL hash.

Comment: MySQL wouldn't know to hash the user's password twice, so unless you're going to write your own authentication plugin for that purpose, I don't think that's realistic.